# Optoisolator, did I connected it right? (Arduino Uno)

Tags: arduino, opto-isolator, zero-crossing

Here is my connection for optoisolator,
[image]
 2 wires, yellow and red are for AC current.
Other 3 in my arduino, `orange pin 2, blue ground and red 5V power`.

And diagram.
[image]

Datasheet for optoisolator:
http://www.vishay.com/docs/83608/h11aa1.pdf

I am using `h11aa1` optoisolator.

Here is my code:

```
const uint8_t ledPin = 13;                          // Digital output pin that has the on board LED
const uint8_t zeroPin = 2;                          // Digital input pin to which the zero crossing detector is connected

uint8_t zeroCounter = 0;
bool zeroState = 0;
bool ledState = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode( ledPin , OUTPUT );                       // Enable output driver for LED pin
  pinMode( zeroPin , INPUT );
}

void loop() {

 Serial.println(digitalRead(zeroPin));
  while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) == zeroState ) { // Wait for the state of the zero crossing detector to change
  zeroState != zeroState;
  zeroCounter++;
  if ( zeroCounter == 50 ) {         // Every 50 zero crossings change the LED state
  Serial.println(zeroState);
    digitalWrite( ledPin , ledState );
    zeroCounter = 0;
  }
  };
}
```

I get always 1 for `digitalRead(zeroPin)` and because of it `Serial.println(zeroState)` will never run...

Anyone can help me make this work?

Comment: I cannot help you on this but I can say that showing the circuit diagram would be a useful addition to this question. Next would be adding an active link to the opto (for the lazy) then possibly reviewing the questions you've already asked and seeing if there is a possibility that you can accept some answers.

Comment: Please check, edited...

Comment: I hate those wires. The steel plug tends to detach from the (often badly soldered) copper wire, leading to an open circuit (that you cannot see thanks to the black rubbery plastic). I would test each and every one of those wires for continuity with a multimeter. EDIT: That code is fundamentally broken so I don't bother discussing it in comments. I'll post an answer.

Comment: LOL zeroState != zeroState, like Dark = Light, or False = True.

Comment: Not my code, but anyway that part isn't importante, just this: digitalRead(zeroPin)

Comment: Also asked on the [Arduino forum](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=376735.0) - with a reference to this question.

Comment: And in that thread you said "I think R3 resistor don't need look at datasheet it can go up to 5 V... Am I right?" WRONG. You do need that collector resistor, or you will force the line high no matter how much the transistor conducts. The opto will die a quick death.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well written question: As much information is provided as possible, thank you for your effort.

This portion of your code is absolutely fine.

```
const uint8_t ledPin = 13;                          // Digital output pin that has the on board LED
const uint8_t zeroPin = 2;                          // Digital input pin to which the zero crossing detector is connected

uint8_t zeroCounter = 0;
bool zeroState = 0;
bool ledState = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode( ledPin , OUTPUT );                       // Enable output driver for LED pin
    pinMode( zeroPin , INPUT );
}
```

This not so much.

```
void loop() {
    Serial.println(digitalRead(zeroPin));
    while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) == zeroState ) { // Wait for the state of the zero crossing detector to change
        zeroState != zeroState;
        zeroCounter++;
        if ( zeroCounter == 50 ) {         // Every 50 zero crossings change the LED state
            Serial.println(zeroState);
            ledState != ledState;
            digitalWrite( ledPin , ledState );
            zeroCounter = 0;
        }
    };
}
```

I cleaned up the formatting so that the control flow is more apparent.

- `Serial.println(digitalRead(zeroPin));` just outputs the state of the zero crossing detector every time the main loop begins again. I don't know why you do this, but fine enough.
- The `while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) == zeroState ) {...` block loops as long as the zero crossing pin is read as equal in value to the variable zeroState. As zeroState is set to 0 at the start of the program and then never modified again, this is equivalent to `while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) == 0 ) {...` which is probably not your intent. If digitalRead(zeroPin) always returns 1 anything within the while loop is actually never executed.
- `zeroState != zeroState;` does nothing useful. != is a relational operator, not an "invert and assign" operator. If you want to invert the value of zeroState from 0 to 1 and vice versa, you would want to write `zeroState = !zeroState;`.
- The led toggling code is fine, again with the exception of `zeroState != zeroState;` which is nonsensical. You probably want `zeroState = !zeroState;`
- Finally the semicolon in `};` is superfluous, it is the ending of the `while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) == zeroState ) {` block. While loops only need them if you omit the body of the loop, e.g. `while(condition);`

What are you trying to achieve with the zeroState variable in general? Are you attempting to only count every other zero crossing?

My take on the code:

```
const uint8_t ledPin = 13;                          // Digital output pin that has the on board LED
const uint8_t zeroPin = 2;                          // Digital input pin to which the zero crossing detector is connected

uint8_t zeroCounter = 0;
bool ledState = 0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode( ledPin , OUTPUT );                       // Enable output driver for LED pin
    pinMode( zeroPin , INPUT );
}

void loop() {
    while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) != 0 ); //wait until zeroPin is low, to make sure that the same zero crossing isn't detected multiple times.
    while ( digitalRead(zeroPin) == 0 ); //wait until zeroPin is high, that's when a zero crossing occurs.
    zeroCounter++;
    if ( zeroCounter >= 50 ) {         // Every 50 zero crossings change the LED state
        zeroCounter = 0;
        Serial.println("50 zero crossings have occurred and 500ms have passed.");
        ledState = !ledState;
        digitalWrite( ledPin , ledState );
    }
}
```

Comment: zeroPin isn't high when `digitalRead(zeroPin) == 0` My problem is no metter if I trun on or off main circuit I will always get `digitalRead(zeroPin) == 1`.

Comment: @VladimirDjukic I understand that, however your code would not have worked either. What happens if you disconnect the optoisolator from the input pin 2 (zeroPin), and toggle the state of that pin manually? Does the code work in that case? To test it, you need to add a pull down resistor from zeroPin to ground, and a pull up momentary switch (or just a length of wire) from zeroPin to +5V. Every button press should simulate one zero crossing.

Comment: It works with button....

Comment: This go in right direction, why it does't work with optoisolator?

Comment: What happens if you connect the opto to the arduino as usual but connect H11AA1 pin 1 to arduino ground and H11AA1 pin 2 to arduino 5V trough a 330 ohm resistor? It should count a "zero crossing" each time you disconnect the resistor from 5V. This is exactly what Marko Buršič said, but it's unclear to me if you tried it or not.

Comment: Yes, it works I get: 50 zero crossings have occurred and 500ms have passed.

Comment: It count no metter if resistor there or not

Comment: In that case it should work on the mains too (with dual 33k resistors in series with the optoisolator input). The 330 ohm resistor was there to limit the current trough the LEDs within the optoisolator. If you omit that resistor the optoisolator is not going to last very long, it is not optional. Please don't omit random resistors.

Comment: Why you think it should work? I am not sure it can read zero crossing on DC power,

Comment: @VladimirDjukic Because you just said that it counted zero crossings when toggling 5V to the optoisolator input side (pins 1 and 2). Every time you disconnected 5V to the opto, the opto saw zero volts. What is zero volts if not a zero crossing?

Comment: I found way to test this with simple code, on AC and DC... I own you a blog post, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

Are you connecting a 10k between 5V and pin number 5? If not, you may have damaged the opto-isolator. The 10k is necessary to give a place for voltage to drop when the opto turns on.  Also like jms said, you probably want to do something like zeroState = !zeroState;

If you think of the pins 4 & 5 of the opto as a switch, ideally if you through the switch it would conduct all the voltage from 5V to ground. Now, if 5V was an ideal supply, that means I = V/R , I = 5V/0 which is infinite. Now in reality what is happening is the switch closed and you probably exceeded the maximum power dissipation of the transistor in the opto, which in this case is 200mW. Might have broke it, might not. Just check it with a voltmeter that has diode mode, pin 5-4 should be about 0.7V forward and inf or open with the leads reversed and pin 5-6 is about 0.7V and inf of open when the leads are reversed.

Comment: +1 for catching that feeding an LED with no series resistor can blow the led (in this case, the led that's "invisibly" hidden inside the optoisolator), but please try to explain slightly more _how/why_ it's needed to protect the LED from overcurrent above the diode's "knee" voltage, and add your comment about  zerostate = !zerostate; into your answer using the "edit" button at the bottom of your answer post.

Comment: I replaced opto and added 10k same result

Answer (score 1):

To chek if the circuit works it is quite simple, simply don't connect AC, use a 5v of arduino and connect a series resitor like 330 ohm, then observe if something changes. There aren't seen 10k and those 33k resitors on the protoboard, have you connected them? Second the input resistors 33k + 33k = 66k might be to much: 230V * 1,41 = 325V peak, 325/66k = 4.9mA, don't know if the forward current is enough even at peak voltage to change the opto state.

Comment: That is the problem I get same result no metter if AC on or off. I tried also with 10K resistor but no result,,